# Как обратиться к элементам структуры в очереди?

Tags: c++, структуры, очередь

Есть очередь, есть структура. Структура помещается в очередь. Как теперь обратиться к элементам структуры?

```
struct Employee
{
string name;
string position;
string birth;
};
int main()
{
Employee emp; 
queue <Employee> q;
q.push(emp);
q.font();
}
```

Comment: `q.front().name`, например. Или сохраните результат в переменной и обращайтесь уже к ней.

Answer (score 1):

> #### std::queue::front
>
> ```
> reference front();
> const_reference front() const;
> ```
>
> Возвращает ссылку на первый элемент очереди.
> — [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/front)

---

> #### std::queue::back
>
> ```
> reference back();
> const_reference back() const;
> ```
>
> Возвращает ссылку на последний элемент очереди.
> — [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/back)

В вашем случае можно обращаться так:

```
q.front().name
```

Или так:

```
q.back().name
```

Разница между ними показана ниже:

```
int main() {
    Employee emp0 = { "Name0" };
    Employee emp1 = { "Name1" };

    queue <Employee> q;
    q.push(emp0);
    q.push(emp1);

    std::cout << q.front().name << std::endl;
    std::cout << q.back().name << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Name0
Name1
```